# Consume WCF Service in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, uwp, universal

I have a `WCF` Service that I use to access my database. It works fine in WPF. But when I add a reference to it (via `Add Service Reference...`) only types are visible through the service namespace, but i need its interface in order to access its methods. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It is good idea to create an extra project of type Class Portable Library targeting Windows 8.1. Then you can consume the service there and reuse this project in the Windows 10 app.

Comment: tried it, didn't help. After a lot of research i didn't find a solution. The service didn't want to generate proxy classes correctly. The solution was to create another service inside the WCF project, only with methods i needed for UWP app, and use its contract, and everything worked fine.